# Passing the field name into a function template

Tags: c++, templates

I am wondering if there is a way I could possibly pass a field name to a function template. Consider the following:

```
struct Type1{
    unsigned int Field1;
    unsigned int Field2;
};

struct Type2{
    unsigned int Field2;
    unsigned int Field3;
};

template <typename TYPE>
bool MyFunction(TYPE _Type){
    if(_Type.Field1==5)
        return false;
}
```

This works fine, however within `MyFunction` I am specifying `.Field1`, is there a way I can pass the name of this field into a template, for example:

```
void TestFunction(){
    Type1 mt1;
    MyFunction(mt1, Field1);
}
```

Clearly, I'm not templating a type here, and I'm at a loss on what this would be called (other than the obvious answer - silly!) so I'm struggling to even search for a solution.

Comment: You may want to look into the pointer-to-member concept.

Comment: Unrelated to the question you're asking, but `_Type` is reserved for the implementation, so you're not allowed to use it (i.e., doing so gives undefined behavior).

Comment: @n.m. Thank you I was just about to reply I'll start searching until the answers came rolling in! :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin Hmm.... Do I take it that's due to starting with an underscore?

Comment: @R4D4 Underscore followed by a capital letter. *One* underscore followed by a lower-case letter is fine – provided it’s not in the global namespace. Uh, this is complicated. ;-) Just don’t use leading underscores.

Comment: Partly -- underscore followed by capital letter is always reserved. Underscore followed by something else would be reserved in global namespace, but would be allowed here (though I'd generally recommend against it anyway).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't pass in pure *names*, because names are not part of the C++ meta-model, but you can pass  **pointers-to-members** to your function:

```
template <typename TYPE, typename T>
bool MyFunction(TYPE obj, T TYPE::*mp)
//                          ^^^^^^^^^
{
    if ((obj.*mp) == 5)
//          ^^^^
        return false;

    // ... <== DON'T FORGET TO RETURN SOMETHING IN THIS CASE,
    //         OTHERWISE YOU WILL GET UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
}
```

Here is how you would use it in a small, complete program:

```
struct Type1{
    unsigned int Field1;
    unsigned int Field2;
};

struct Type2{
    unsigned int Field2;
    unsigned int Field3;
};

int main()
{
    Type1 t1;
    Type2 t2;
    MyFunction(t1, &Type1::Field1);
    MyFunction(t2, &Type2::Field3);
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4sAas7$50).

Answer (score 8):

You can pass a [pointer-to-member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx):

```
template <typename T>
bool MyFunction(T& type, int T::*field){
    if (type.*field == 5)
        return false;
}

MyFunction(mt1, &Type1::Field1);
```